# How to use vlookup to look up words in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is a mockup of my data:

[image: screenshot]

Column I has categories of food and column H has the codes for those categories.

Column E has sub-categories, which is what I need to work with.  It contains the category name plus a sequential number distinguishing the sub-category.

In columns F and G, I need to find the code and name for the parent category from columns H and I.  The image shows column G already filled in.

The actual data has 348 categories and 1000 sub-categories.

I tried to use Vlookup, which gives me #N/A, a value not available error.  For example, I tried this for the column G value:

```
=VLOOKUP(E4,H4:I6,2,FALSE)
```

How do I lookup the values for columns F and G for each value in column E?

Comment: I have added some mock data, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. But i am not sure how to add the matching category code in the adjacent column?

Comment: It works! Could you please explain what the left and right functions do?

Comment: Also, is there another method for the codes for unsorted data?

Comment: Yes, the data was made up. Yes, that's precisely it. But, in the original data(not the made up one) there is no obvious connection in the name of the category code and the sub category code  or category name.

Comment: In your revised example, you included variation in the category code, so the RIGHT function I originally mentioned in a comment isn't a general solution.  The answer uses INDEX and MATCH instead.  Let me know if you have any questions.  If the answer solves the problem for you, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You have two columns to fill in.  Let's start with category name in column G.  Trying to do this with VLOOKUP would be convoluted because the values in column E don't match the values in column I.  However, you're in luck because of your naming convention.  The column E sub-category names contain the category name as the first portion, and the sequence number is always three digits.  We can use this to directly extract the category name.

Excel has string functions to do this kind of manipulation of character strings.  LEFT(string,number) will give you that **number** of the leftmost characters in **string**.  Similarly, RIGHT(string,number) would give you that **number** of the rightmost characters.  So if you wanted to extract the sub-category sequence number for E4, it would be: RIGHT(E4,3).

Another string function is LEN, which gives you the length (number of characters) in a string.  To extract the category name for G4, which is all of the characters except the last four (i.e., space plus sequence number), you can use:

```
=LEFT(E4,LEN(E4)-4)
```

Now you have the category name and you can use that to lookup the associated category code.  Unfortunately, VLOOKUP has a limitation that the comparison is always done in the leftmost column of the lookup range.  Your table is set up with the code in the leftmost column.    Instead, we can use a combination of INDEX and MATCH.  MATCH will locate a matching value and INDEX will select the associated value from a different column.  In F4, we can use:

```
=INDEX(H4:H6,MATCH(G4,I4:I6,0))
```

INDEX returns the value from the range H4:H6 for the row within that range given by the MATCH function.  MATCH identifies the row in I4:I6 where the value is an exact match to the value in G4 (the `0` at the end designates an exact match, so the sequence of the data isn't important).  In this example, Fruit matches the first row within the range, so INDEX returns `X040001` from the first row of its range.